# Instant updaing with codepush

Tags: react-native, expo

Does expo do the job codePush does for us.
I want to have the ability to update the app instantly without the need for the user to update the app on appStore or playStore. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when you want to update your app, just Publish again from Expo CLI.
>   Your users will download the new JS the next time they open the app.
>   To ensure your users have a seamless experience downloading JS
>   updates, you may want to enable background JS downloads. However,
>   there are a couple of reasons why you might want to rebuild and resubmit
>   the native binaries

[Offline-support](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/offline-support.html)

Read Article here :-  [Building-standalone-apps](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/building-standalone-apps.html)